# How do I fix this Django error "Exception Type: OperationalError Exception Value: no such table?"

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pinax

I've finally installed all the requirements (so i think!) of a Django project, and I'm trying to get a local install running on my Mac (OSX 10.4).

I'm getting the following error:

> Blockquote
>   OperationalError at /
>   no such table: django_content_type
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Exception Type: OperationalError
>   Exception Value:
>   no such table: django_content_type
>   Exception Location:     /Users/Diesel/Desktop/DjangoWork/pinax-ev/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py
>   in execute, line 170
>   Python Executable:      /Users/Diesel/Desktop/DjangoWork/pinax-ev/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.5.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Did you run `./manage.py syncdb` to create all your tables?
- Do you have `django.contrib.contenttypes` in your INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`?

As an unlikely third option:

- Does your project/app use the Django app "South"? If so, you would also need to run `./manage.py migrate` to make sure all tables get created.

Forgetting any of those items would cause the table(s) for ContentType not to be generated.

Comment: Thanks! 

I ended figuring out the ./manage.py syncdb to create tables...
Although for some reason the "migrate" command isn't available to me... (I'm using sqlite3, but I'm moving to mysql tonight on my local machine).

I actually think i do need "South" where can I find that?

Thanks!

Comment: the `migrate` command is added by South. you can find out more about South here: http://south.aeracode.org/

Comment: Any other reasons why I would get this error? I have checked all the options, but none of them seem to help. This is the line where it goes wrong: 'content_type_id': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model).pk,

Comment: @Sam Stoelinga That line is probably somehow called before the tables are properly created

Comment: Note: `syncdb` was removed in Django 1.9

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29683785/3228591) for the alternative to `syncdb` in Django 1.9+

Answer (score 13):

Using django version 1.10, I had to perform:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when your table information is not there in the database or there is some conflict with your existing database. For example you have changed your Database column name or database name.
Below steps will help you get rid of this error.

1. Look for **INSTALLED_APPS = []** into the file "**setting.py**", your app name must be there. for ex: INSTALLED_APPS = ['app'/{whatever is your app name in inverted comma}]
2. Run the commands:

> `python manage.py makemigrations app`
> (whatever is your app name-my case- "app")

> `python manage.py migrate`

> `python manage.py runserver`