# What should I use instead of syncdb in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

Take a look at this:

```
$ pypy ./manage.py syncdb
/usr/lib64/pypy-2.4.0/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py:24: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9
  warnings.warn("The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

(cut)
```

I ran a [quick google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=django%20syncdb%201.9), but could not find the answer - what should I be using instead of `syncdb`?

Comment: Actually, now that I that I look again, it's right there: `syncdb has been deprecated and replaced by migrate`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`syncdb` is deprecated because of [the migration system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/), introduced with [django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations).

Now you can **track** your changes using `makemigrations`. This transforms your model changes into python code to make them deployable to another databases. When you have further modifications you need applied to the database, you can use [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

After you created the migrations you have to **apply** them: `migrate`.

So instead of using `syncdb` you should use `makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Workflow on development after you changed something in your models:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

And on your production system:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Bonus: you do not need to run `migrate` for each change. If you have multiple changes not applied yet django will run them in the correct order for you.

Comment: It is the best new feature ;)

Comment: NOTE: `makemigrations` may require the module name as a parameter.

Comment: This is terrible advice. If you're installing an app with a dozen migrations to a blank database, you should never run `migrate` because that will be a huge waste of time. @Don Mums answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 64):

You should definitely use [migration system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/). Which lets you track changes in your `models.py`, and create migrations for the database. The migration system uses the commands [`makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) to create migrations and [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) to migrate the database.

If for whatever reason you need to create a database the same way `syncdb` did it there is command flag that causes `migrate` to work the same way. You should only do this if you **REALLY** need it and you know what you are doing. For example to create an empty database on for a continuous integration system of your choice.

```
python manage.py migrate auth
# performs migrations for auth and contenttypes contrib apps

python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
# creates the rest of the database
```

Tested on Django 1.9.1.

Comment: +1 for the actual solution, this should be the answer. While you should use migrations for production releases when actively developing from scratch it is easier to just wipe out the DB and start over than need to run 500 migrations. I routinely run `dropdb mydb && createdb mydb && python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` whenever I make a change.

Comment: `--run-syncdb` only seems to work on apps that don't have migrations. I used the following workaround:

`find -name "migrations" -exec mv {}/__init__.py {}/__init__ \; && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && find -name "migrations" -exec mv {}/__init__ {}/__init__.py \; && python manage.py migrate --fake`

Answer (score 9):

You should use the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands that were introduced in django 1.7

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 3):

`syncdb` has some problem with db migration. so, after django 1.7 `makemigrations` and `migrate` have been introduced. 
Now in django 1.9 `syncdb` has been deprecated.
try
1. `python manage.py makemigrations` which detects changes in db and creates one `.py` file as inside migrations folder
2. `python manage.py migrate` will apply the migrations to the database