# What's the alternative to syncdb command in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django

Till v1.8, I used to issue following command and it used to create tables for me and ask for creating a new user.

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Now since this command has been removed in 1.9, how do I do it?

Comment: Check following link: might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683494/what-should-i-use-instead-of-syncdb-in-django-1-9

Comment: I see, there's `createsuperuser` for that.

Answer (score 2):

From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

> This command has been deprecated in favor of the migrate command, which performs both the old behavior as well as executing migrations.

For older software you may want to use

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: It's not doing that latter part i.e. asking to create a superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Django migrations.

First usage :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app
python manage.py migrate
```

It replace South in Django 1.7.
If your want more details : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/